# Use restriction on locating facilities and route finding

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, arcgis-10.6, network-dataset

On a project I came to the following problem in ArcGIS 10.6.1:

I have a road network which consists of paths, local roads, national roads and highways. I have also a bunch of possible facility locations. Some of the facilities are located near a highway. Since the facilities cannot have a direct access to highways, I want to prevent the facilities to be located on highways.

I found this question already here: [Restricting portions of road network from analysis in ArcGIS Network Analyst?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14295/restricting-portions-of-road-network-from-analysis-in-arcgis-network-analyst)

I want to apply @Alex Tereshenkov idea of not locating the facility near those restricted routes, but to still let them run through them. I added in my road network layer a coloumn called `RESTRICTED` (Type: Integer) with the following idea behind:

```
0 = no restriction  
1 = prohibited to locate facilities on this road
```

I fail however to define in the network dataset that the facilities are prohibited to be located on highways.

What am I missing here?

The very same problem to tell the network dataset that some roads are unilateral while others are bilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, read [Using parameters with network attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/using-parameters-with-network-attributes.htm) to understand the concept behind networks and restrictions. Then using the information found in [Types of evaluators used by a network](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/types-of-evaluators-used-by-a-network.htm), we can use the pre-composed one-way restriction:

> These expressions determine the permitted directions of travel based on the text value in the Oneway field:
>
> ```
> FT or F = Travel is only permitted in the digitized direction of the line feature (the from-to direction).
> TF or T = Travel is only permitted against the digitized direction of the line feature (the to-from direction).
> N = Travel is not permitted in either direction.
> Any other value = Travel is permitted in both directions.
> ```

By using the FT or F, TF or T, N and any other value, the restriction set in the `Oneway` coloumn of the attribute table, does the trick.